# redirecting some STDERR message in R

Tags: r

I am creating a R tool for Galaxy and I have some issue with STDERR
By default Galaxy mark as "finished with error" any tool that write something on STDERR. My R script use the package latice which send its opening message ("you are using latice version xxxx") on STDERR

I would like to avoid this but not redirecting all messages from STDERR to another connection, as some of them may be right to tag the tool as "finish with error".

Is there a way to do choose to redirect all STDERR messages somewhere else for some part of the code only ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Yes, use `sink()`, probably in combination with `try()` or `tryCatch()`

Comment: Dear Andrie thank you for your answer. After some try, you proposal seem to be a good solution. Cheers